# file_get_contents, certain parameters?

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I am currently using `file_get_contents` as I do not wish to use an `iframe`.

I am doing the `file_get_contents` on a page which holds content such as the following:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>title</title>
</head>
<body style="margin:0; padding:0;">
    <a href="http://www.site.com" target="_blank" style="border:none;"><img src="http://www.site.com/image.jpg" style="border:none;" /></a>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
//some javascript here
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I basically want to do a `file_get_conents`, return it, and only echo out the following on my site:

```
<a href="http://www.site.com" target="_blank" style="border:none;"><img src="http://www.site.com/image.jpg" style="border:none;" /></a>
```

How can I do this? So when doing a `file_get_contents`, I avoid getting all of the extra stuff, and just get what I actually need, the `a href` and whats inside it.

Comment: How to identify the desired HTML part? Does it have a certain position in the DOM tree, a known ID, class or name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use regular expressions:

```
$html=file_get_contents($file);
if(preg_match("#<a.*?</a>#is", $html, $match)) echo $match[0]; //$match[0] contains the filtered html
```